# Recorrer datos de una consulta a la BD en Jade no los muestra

Tags: nodejs, jade

Tengo una ruta donde hago una consulta a la base de datos, para tratar de mandarlos a la vista de este modo

```
router.get('/all', (req, res, next) => {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', (err, rows, fields) => {
        res.render('index', { rows: 'rows' })
    });
});
```

Posterior desde la vista trato de recorrer los valores de este modo

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
  ul
  each value in rows
      li = value.nameUser
```

No me muestra errores, pero en lugar de mostrarme los resultados; me aparece lo siguiente

```
= value.nameUser
= value.nameUser
= value.nameUser
= value.nameUser
```

Me gustaría me ayuden a identificar el por que, gracias

Comment: ponerle las comillas según yo, era para pasarlo como arreglo asociativo, pero igual deja pruebo y te comento @Trauma

Comment: Se las quité y funcionó , después me mostró [Object Object] y lo solucione pasando q rows por el método stringify pero ahora esta el problema que cada carácter lo pone en un renglón distinto @Trauma

Comment: He mirado la doc, y **debería** funcionar sin las comillas. La verdad es que no se que mas decirte, tendrás que esperar a ver si alguien responde. Lo siento :-(